# QT QML + C++ MVVM

Tags: qt, mvvm, qml

As far as I know in QT QML is not possible to instantiate a C++ class in QML Component, unless it is a QQuickItem.
I would not like to put all ViewModels on ViewEngine context because it is a very bad pratice create all classes in memory without using.

My question is: How can I instantiate a C++ ViewModel ou Services/API from a single QML component without usnig ViewEngine Context.
Do ViewModels have to be QQuickItem type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ objects do not need to be QQuickItems, they need to be QObjects. You just need to [register](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterType) your class with the QQmlEngine, like this:

```
qmlRegisterType<MyObject>("my.component.library", 1, 0, "MyObject");
```

Then in your qml files, you can instantiate that class like this:

```
import my.component.library 1.0

MyObject {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is this the best way to call a C++ Backend service with QML ?  I am beginner in QT/QML.

Comment: It depends what want to do with the object. I would say it is more common to instantiate C++ objects from C++ code, and expose them to QML with [qmlRegisterSingletonInstance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonInstance) or [setContextProperty](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty). But there are times when creating an instance directly from QML makes sense too.

Comment: Using qmlRegisterSingletonInstance or setContextProperty means I have to create/instantiate ALL classes on application startup. It seems a naivy approach for big applications.

Comment: That's why I said it depends. It's not naive to instantiate at startup a lot of things that need to only be created once. But if you want to instantiate things whenever they're needed, you have that option too.